# Can my data be described as a random walk or not?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, random-walk

I'm trying to figure out whether the observed "time series" can be described as a random walk or not. Unfortunately a major problem regarding my data is in time intervals:

Problem:
    Time intervals are not equal. Example:

```
TimePoints = 1854, 1901, 1914, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1950, 1958, 1974, 1980, 1984, 1986,1988,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000
```

Associated data are cumulative values and go like this:

```
Values: 40, 51, 53, 60, 61, 65, 83, 88, 113, 125, 97, 81, 76, 77, 78, 79, 81, 73, 72, 71, 64, 75, 74, 73, 68
```

If time intervals were equal then I wouldn't have this confusion, but now (due to my lack of experience) I am puzzled whether or not my data can be described as a random walk.

Any suggestions?? Is there any test designed to handle such situations?

Comment: @Gavin Simpson's answer on Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180545/time-series-modelling-with-irregular-data) suggests you can expand your vector with NAs for all the integer timepoints not available, and then use the ordinary anova() function in R. I just simulated an AR(.6) series, threw some NAs into it, and anova() didn't complain, FWIW.